# Meteor solr-client package not installing

Tags: solr, meteor, npm

When I issue add module command :

```
 npm install solr-client
```

We get the following error.

> Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log. Started MongoDB. Errors
>   prevented startup:   While building the application:
>   node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/request/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/run.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/request/node_modules/bl/test/sauce.js:1:15:
>   Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/JSONStream/index.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/json-bigint/node_modules/bignumber.js/test/browser/bignumber-vs-number.html:1:
>   Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/json-bigint/node_modules/bignumber.js/test/browser/console-errors.html:1:
>   Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/json-bigint/node_modules/bignumber.js/test/browser/every-test.html:1:
>   Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/json-bigint/node_modules/bignumber.js/test/browser/quick-test.html:1:
>   Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/json-bigint/node_modules/bignumber.js/test/browser/single-test.html:1:
>   Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/json-bigint/node_modules/bignumber.js/doc/API.html:1:
>   Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/json-bigint/node_modules/bignumber.js/perf/bignumber-vs-bigdecimal.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>       node_modules/solr-client/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid/test/test.html:1:
>   bad formatting in HTML template
>
> ```
> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
> ```

Comment: put npm command on its own line

Answer (score 1):

By default, meteor will try to build all *.js and *.html files inside your project directory. Which is to say that it doesn't play well with NPM modules. A way to avoid it is create a root directory to install such packages starting with a . as this is ignored by meteor.